# Will sysdate() be accurate in the place of currentdate()?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using a stored procedure to write the date and time in a file. Also, I have scheduled my procedure to 1 AM daily.

My code to get the date and time is

```
select to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'DDMMYYYY/HH:MI:SS') from dual;
```

But, the displayed date was the previous day's date. Will sysdate() works in this place correctly?

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` gives me today's date and time and it is the ANSI way to do this.  Check your localization settings.

Comment: All are correct. When I execute the same query alone, it gives me the correct result. But, the problem is only when it is being scheduled

Comment: Since you say the issue comes at 1AM, it seems there is a time zone issue.  However, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `SYSDATE` will return the same values.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff: that is not entirely true. `sysdate` returns a `date` with time information but **without** a time zone whereas `current_timestamp` returns a `timestamp` **with** time zone

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are correct.  I should have said that after the `TO_CHAR`, both will return the same value.

Comment: show us the results of select localtimestamp, current_timestamp, sysdate from dual;

Comment: All were same @kevisky